# How does supercompilers relate to macro tree transducers?

Tags: proof-techniques, compilers, functional-programming, proof-assistants

Supercompilers can be used as a generalisation of deforestation of a functional program. Macro Tree Transducers composition can be used to the same effect, using a completely different approach. What is the relationship between those?